# kafka-python raise kafka.errors.ConsumerFetchSizeTooSmall

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I'm writing a simple code in python 2.7 that is consuming messaging from an apache kafka topic. The code is the following:

```
from kafka import SimpleConsumer,KafkaClient
group = "my_group_test"
client = KafkaClient('localhost:9092')
cons = SimpleConsumer(client, group, "my_topic")
messages = cons.get_messages(count=1000,block=False)
```

But is raising this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/simple.py", line 285, in get_messages
    update_offset=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/simple.py", line 320, in _get_message
    self._fetch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/simple.py", line 425, in _fetch
    raise ConsumerFetchSizeTooSmall()
kafka.errors.ConsumerFetchSizeTooSmall
```

How could i modify this parameter (ConsumerFetchSize) in order to make this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution,
using the parameter [max_buffer_size](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc/kafka.consumer.html?highlight=max_buffer_su) in the SimpleConsumer.

The working code is:

```
#the size is adherent with my need but is totally arbitrary
cons = SimpleConsumer(client, group, "my_topic",max_buffer_size=9932768)
```